# Laravel Eloquent get given nested level

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a multiple level User model , each User can have childs and parents

```
public function children() {

    return $this->hasmany($this,'parent_id')->with('children');
}

public function parent() {

    return $this->belongsTo($this,'parent_id')->with('parent');
}
```

Then on tinker:

```
$User = App\User::find(9)
$user->children
```

This give me all the children of the given user on multiple level (Cilds of childs ...) : http://pastebin.com/8NeF7aP9

I'm trying to get the children of each level, with the output above:

level 1 will be users: 10, 11
Level 2 will be users: 12, 13 (children of children)

Any hint on how to do that ?

Comment: a shema could help http://prntscr.com/bsoy64

Comment: You are getting nested children now, so you probably should rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm getting the all tree but i can't get a specific leaf node, for example get the count of layer 2 in this http://prntscr.com/bsoy64

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get all items for definite level

```
public function usersOnLevel($level)
{
    if ($level == 1) {
        return User::where('parent_id', null)->lists('id');
    } else {
        return User::whereIn('parent_id', $this->usersOnLevel($level - 1))->lists('id');
    }
}
```

Here is my table http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot2016-07-1423-17-39.php

Here is output http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot2016-07-1423-15-45.php

Or do you need somewhat else?

Answer (score 1):

You can also get children by levels for definite user

```
public function usersOnLevel($level, User $startUser)
{
    if ($level == 1) {
        return User::where('parent_id', $startUser->id)->lists('id')->toArray();
    } else {
        return User::whereIn('parent_id', $this->usersOnLevel($level - 1, $startUser))->lists('id')->toArray();
    }
}
```

output http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot2016-07-1423-18-50.php

Answer (score 0):

a shema could help to understand http://prntscr.com/bsoy64

Comment: This answer should be removed